# Does nested class (inner or static) that is private may has method with public acesses?

Tags: java, nested, inner-classes, access-modifiers, static-classes

I'm reading a book for java beginners. i saw an example that private nested inner class was declared with a public method. Can someone explain me the meaning and how can i decide if a private nested class (static/inner) methods should be private or public?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A private nested class is only visible inside its enclosing class, and the enclosing class (and other nested classes) can access its private methods.

So making their methods public or private doesn't matter much to the compiler, unless of course the nested class extends a base class or implements an interface, and thus *has* to have its overriding methods public. Making methods public can also be necessary of they're called using reflaction (for example if its onstances are serialized as JSON or XML, or if they're accessed in a JSP).

I tend to choose what to make public and private using the same rules as if the class wasn't nested. That makes it clearer (to me) that some private methods are not not part of its public API and thus not supposed to be used outside the nested class itself. And if I ever refactor the nested class as a top-level class, I don't need to change anything.

Comment: When saying, "and the enclosing class (and other nested classes) can access its private methods". I'm a little bit confuse and can't understand what you mean and other nested classes. Can you please clarify it so i will feel more comfortable :)

Comment: The enclosing class Foo can have two nested classes Foo.Bar and Foo.Baz. Bar can access the private members of Baz, and vice-versa.

Comment: @Eitanos30 'private' basically means: all code in this very file that you are editing can see this method / field that you declared private and call it (method) or read and write it (field); all other code (so all code written in any other .java source file) cannot.

Comment: @rzwitserloot that's not entirely true. Two top-level classes defined in the same file can't access the private members of the other one.

Comment: @JB Nizet, is it possible to have two top-level classes in java?

Comment: Yes. But only ne public class per file. It's discouraged though, and very few people do that.

Comment: Also a public nested/inner class within the same class may extend the private nested class, exposing its publics. / The situation is much the same as having a default access ("package private") class with public methods.

Comment: @JBNizet Hence the 'basically'. Simple explanations that fit for 99% of use cases seem appropriate for someone reading 'java for beginners'.

Comment: @JBNizet, so if only one public class per file, so how can you have more than one top- level classes?

Comment: @Eitanos by having a non-public top level class: `public class Foo {} class Bar {}`

Comment: @JB Nizet, Sorry but i didn't understand. Is there a good example in java src code? i  think it will be more clear for me by example

Comment: ok i see i confuse between inner class of outer class and an two top level classes. I will try to understand  the difference between them.Hopefully i will understand.  thanks you

Comment: Can you tell me please what is the syntax for accessing top level class like Bar?

Comment: It's a top-level class. I.e. a normal class, like all the classes you always write. You access it like any other class. Since it's not public, you can access it only from classes in the same package.